# how to read a large file (at most 2 000 000 000 char) and stock them

Tags: c, overflow, buffer

I'm trying to solve a problem, for that I have an input file containing a maze, I know how o solve the maze but I don't know how to stock the maze.
I can't stock it in a char array because the file can be at most 2 billions char.
I don't know how to stock the file without exploding the buffer...
the file is read with the read command (fread isn't allowed).

Comment: Can you use features of the operating system such as memory-mapped files to treat the file as an array of bytes directly? What do you mean "isn't allowed" -- isn't allowed by who?

Comment: Are you looking for lseek64 ?

Comment: it's a school project, we only have a very restricted number of programms allowed: open, close, write, read, malloc and free. but we can code whatever function we want...

Comment: Questions to consider are: Can you usefully represent the maze with less memory than its “image” as a character array? E.g., by converting it into an abstract graph of edges and vertices (if you have studied that)? If not, can you navigate the maze without reading the entire thing at once, such as by moving back and forth in the file to look at different parts of the maze at different times? (This should usually be done with the `fseeko` and `ftello` functions, which you do not mention as allowed.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: reading the assignment, I think the OP was being directed towards your second suggestion. "How to handle *huge* files" is a pretty good exercise, and somehow trying to stuff all of it into memory is simply not always an option. It'll only use one single 'line' of memory (safe to say these are lines?) and I don't believe you can do with less than that.

Answer (score 2):

From your description sounds like you need to read a maze and then store a copy of the solved maze.

Let's asume that your maze would be stored as a bi-dimensional array of chars, with one char representing bricks of walls -e.g. '*'- and another one being the open space -e.g. ' '-, so a small 8 x 8 maze might look like this:

```
    ****** *
    *      *
    * **** *
    * *    *
    * *** **
    *   *  *
    *** ****
    *** ****
```

Then you need to do your solving, and store the maze with a char representing the steps of the path followed to solve it. Which -assuming the char is '+' , it will look like this:

```
    ******+*
    *++++++*
    *+ *** *
    *+ *   *
    *+*** **
    *+++*  *
    ***+****
    ***+****
```

It it was me -and being the goal to use little memory-, the first thing that I would do is to convert the maze to bits, where the asterisk would be represented by a 1 and the space by a 0. The resulting map would be 8 times smaller. Then I would do my solving but like I can't store the '+' in the map -bits can only have 2 values-, I would instead store the location of each of the steps on a linked list. Then I will save the output maze by reading every location of the map and checking it in the list, if it is there I will output a '+', otherwise I'll check the bit and output '*' if its 1, and ' ' if its 0.

Like this is a college project, I am not goign to give you all the code here -as you should write it yourself- but I'll give you enough clues on the form of some unoptimized code. ;-)

```
struct pos {
    int x,y;
    struct pos *next;
};

struct pos *step_list=NULL;

#define MAZE_WIDTH_BITS  ((MAZE_WIDTH + 7) / 8)

unsigned char bitmaze[MAZE_HEIGHT][MAZE_WIDTH_BITS];

int getbit(int x,int y)
{
    unsigned char v = bitmaze[y][(x / 8)];


    v >>= 7 - (x % 8);
    return (v & 1);
}


void save_maze(FILE *fp)
{
    int x,y,found;
    struct pos *cur_step;

    for(y=0;y<MAZE_HEIGHT;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<MAZE_WIDTH;x++)
        {
            found=0;
            cur_step=step_list;
            while(cur_step && !found)
            {
                if(cur_step->x==x && cur_step->y==y)
                     found=1;
                else
                    cur_step=cur_step->prox;
            }
            if(found)
                fputc('+',fp);
            else
                fputc( getbit(x,y) ? '*' : ' ',fp);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help you.
guilleamodeo.

Comment: Wouha, great idea! I only have one setback, I have one way in and possibly several way outs, but maybe I can set the way out to an empty bit for the calculations and put it back to its original value aftewards...

Comment: well in fact the problem is that there is special char for the way in and out and I think you can have a way out in the middle of the maze...

Comment: Maybe you can use one linked list for the way in and few others for the way out. That will also allow to use different chars for each solution. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just allocate memory for 2000000000 char array? The only limit is your pc memory.  If there is sufficient contiguous address space left, there is no problem.

You can try something like `char *my_maze = (char*) malloc((2000000000 * sizeof(char)));`

Comment: I heard that it was a very bad thing to do to allocate such a big size, that there was a very high risk of overflow? isn't there

Comment: @istovatis Certainly you want "... = (char *) malloc((2000000000 ...".  (Add the `*`.).  Further recommend `char *my_maze = malloc(2000000000 * sizeof(*my_maze))`.

Comment: “PC memory” is not the “only limit”. The limit may be higher (provided as virtual memory by the operating system) or lower (if restricted by the operating system, the C implementation, or resource limits set by the system administrator).

Comment: @zopa: It is not bad to allocate a lot of memory if you are making good use of it and are not interfering with other important uses of the system (such as other users trying to get work done). The risk of “overflow” by your program is unrelated to buffer size; it is determined by writing correct code. Or, if you mean the risk of running out of memory and not getting the amount you requested, this will be determined for you. `malloc` will return zero if it cannot provide the memory. In that case, you must find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

well you can use a linked list where each node contains a character, it will take a lot  , A LOT , of space but it'll do it

Comment: with 2Gb it doesn't matter what you do , it'll always consume a lot of memory , A LOT.

Comment: but why not just use a char array instead?

Comment: I think you should go with something not contiguous

Comment: Although a linked list might avoid having a single large allocation, it'll also use WAY more total memory, and be extremely slow to work with...